# Navigate to a webpage and then redirect after X seconds

Tags: php, redirect

I am not a `php` programmer so bear with me on this one...
I am trying to navigate to a specific URL and then redirect to another page after 3 seconds. However, the second line of the redirect does not work!

Please see below my `php` code

```
<?php
header("Location: http://someurl.com");
header("Refresh: 3;url=http://www.somenewurl.com/index.php");
?>
```

I reached the first URL - meaning the first line is executed. However, the redirect in the second line does not happen...

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.somenewurl.com/index.php">';
```

but no idea why would you need it, not many sites are doing this, do not use refresh, only header Location and after it execute exit();

Comment: Thanks for your reply - However, the code does not redirect me to the new URL.I am trying to navigate from my site to another site (that is the first line) and after the user sees that page for 3 seconds, redirect him to another page...

Comment: Ahh, got it! Then remove second header, redirect him by first header there and now he is on page#2, on this second page put into `<head> </head>` this code `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.gobacktooldurl.com/">` and it will move back everyone who already will be at this page.

Comment: The problem is that this second page is not mine :-( So I can not change it... Isn't there a way to navigate from the second page which is not mine to a third page?

Comment: No, there is no way until you ask some admin of second page. You have had said this before.